# .NET Core 2 project - TypeLoadException

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a .NET core 2 project cloned on my newly bought Laptop (running on Win10). I have installed VS Community 2017 along with .Net core 2 framework. When I load the solution, I have working on my old PC, I got dependency errors marked with a yellow triangle in the solution explorer. These are two types:

*Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 2.0.0-preview1-final depends on System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe (>= 4.4.0-preview1-25219-04) but System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 4.4.0-preview1-25219-04 was not found. An approximate best match of System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 4.4.0-preview1-25305-02 was resolved.*

*Package 'librdkafka.redist 0.11.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.*

Apart from these warnings, I have a runtime exception saying: 
*System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.AuthenticationOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.'*

I have the AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation NuGet package referenced with version 1.0.0, which does not look 100% right to me, but it has been working
well so far.
This is the exactly same project as the one working on my old PC, nothing changed.

[warnings in solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcXaK.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: The warning is meaningless, at least in terms of getting your project running. Since .NET Core 2.0 implements .NET Standard 2.0, which has very large API footprint, VS now allows you to reference .NET Framework libraries in .NET Core projects. However, not *all* .NET Framework APIs are supported, so you get this warning, letting you know that the library may make unsupported API calls. You should fully test the library, first, and if you determine everything is okay, then you can safely suppress the warning and forget about it.

Comment: The actual exception sounds like you've got mismatched NuGets installed. ASP.NET Core 2.0 utilizes Identity 2.0, and there were a ton of backwards incompatible changes from Identity 1.0. The `AspNet.Security.Oauth.Validation` package looks like a problem as well. All the ASP.NET Core stuff is in he `Microsoft.AspNetCore` namespace.

Comment: Are you using wildcard versions? Like `4.4.0-*`?  You should avoid doing that, if you want to have same behavior when restoring on different machines

Answer (score 0):

find

```
PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="2.0.0-preview1-final"
```

and remove . then build it.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `remove .`?